# Where to add code to custom gallery shortcode

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using the information here http://ieg.wnet.org/2016/02/replacing-default-wordpress-gallery-shortcode/ as the basis for a custom gallery shortcode, and trying to create this carousel slider https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider.  Problem is I don't know how exactly to implement it.

The images and everything up until then shows in the source code, but then nothing after it.

```
   <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:800px;height:356px;overflow:hidden;">

    <?php

foreach ( $images as $image ) {
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'homepage-thumb');
    $thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
    $fullsize = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'service-page');
    $fullsize = $fullsize[0];
    $gallery .= "<div><img data-u='image' src='".$thumbnail."'><img data-u='thumb' src='".$fullsize."'></div>";  
    }
return $gallery;
?>       
         </div>
```

It's probably something simple, this is just far past my base of knowledge when it comes to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the value instead of printing it to the web page. Use `echo` instead of `return`. Also make sure you `echo` it in each iteration of the loop so you don't just print one image, but all of them.

```
<div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:800px;height:356px;overflow:hidden;">
<?php
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'homepage-thumb');
        $thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
        $fullsize = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'service-page');
        $fullsize = $fullsize[0];
        $gallery .= "<div><img data-u='image' src='".$thumbnail."'><img data-u='thumb' src='".$fullsize."'></div>"; 
        echo $gallery; 
    }
?>       
</div>
```